# VBA save the file on desktop, if name already taken add a numer to it

Tags: vba

The piece of code below saves a "Test" file on the desktop.
But if you run macro again, the file is overwritten.
How do I amend the code so that it saves the file as Test2 etc. if Test name is already taken?
*"Test" name is different each month.

```
Dim Path As String

Monthh = MonthName(Month(Date))
TargetName = "Test"
TargetBook.Windows(1).Caption = TargetName


Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & TargetName & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Close
MsgBox TargetName & " has been saved on your desktop."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of a loop and checking whether the file exists allows you to save any number of times:

```
Private Sub Test()
   TargetName = GetTargetName(Path & TargetName & ".xlsx")
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs TargetName
   MsgBox TargetName & " has been saved on your desktop."
End Sub

Private Function GetTargetName(ByVal TargetName As String) As String
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim fso As FileSystemObject

   i = 1
   GetTargetName = TargetName
   Set fso = New FileSystemObject

   Do While fso.FileExists(GetTargetName)
      i = i + 1
      GetTargetName = fso.GetBaseName(TargetName) & i & "." & fso.GetExtensionName(TargetName)
   Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. However, now the file is saved in the Documents folder, not on desktop. And MsgBox is always the same: "Test has been saved on your desktop." (it does not include actual name, like Test2, Test3 etc.

Comment: Question 1:  I tried your code and it saved to the Desktop so I'm not sure of the issue.  Question 2:  That's because you are using `TargetName` which has the value `Test`.

Comment: I amended the code so the MsgBox will show the correct file name.

Answer (score 1):

I've used varieties of something like this:

```
Dim TargetName As String, FileBaseName As String
Dim i As Integer

TargetName = "Test"
TargetBook.Windows(1).Caption = TargetName
' change your variable - can't use Path as a variable
TargetPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"

' if a file with same name already exists in the folder
' add a # to it until we have a unique name
i = 1
FileBaseName = TargetName
Do Until Dir$(TargetPath & TargetName & ".xlsx") = ""
    TargetName = FileBaseName & i
    i = i + 1
Loop

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs TargetPath & TargetName & ".xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if a file exists, use the `Dir` function:

```
If Len(Dir(Path & TargetName)) > 0 Then '   file already currently exists
    '    need to get a new unique file name
End If
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this :

```
If Dir(Path & TargetName) <> "" Then 'Check if file exist
    TargetName = val(TargetName)+1 & Mid(TargetName,Len(CVar(TargetName))+1)
Else
```

To make this work you will have to get number at the front end of TargetName for example : **1file**

What do this code do :

`val(TargetName)` return the number in your file name here **1**

`val(TargetName)+1` add 1 so 1 + 1 = **2**

`Mid(TargetName,Len(CVar(TargetName))+1)` delete the number of the string so it return : **file**

`val(TargetName)+1 & Mid(TargetName,Len(CVar(TargetName))+1)` will give you **2file**