# File Downloader is Overwriting in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently creating a program that downloads URL links as PDF and stores it into my local storage. The problem is that, when it encounters a duplicate name then it overwrites. Any thoughts on instead of overwriting the existing file, It should just add (2) on the end.

My code here is

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
      ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
      ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As Long

Sub DownloadFile()

Dim downloadStatus As Variant
Dim Url As String
Dim destinatioFile_Local As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) = True
Url = (Cells(i, 1))
destinationFile_local = "C:\Users\name\Desktop\test" & filename(Cells(i, 1))
downloadStatus = URLDownloadToFile(0, Url, destinationFile_local, 0, 0)
If downloadStatus = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Downloaded"
    Else
    MsgBox "Download fail"
End If
i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub

Function filename(file_fullname) As String

filename = Mid(file_fullname, InStrRev(file_fullname, "/") + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: How about checking if the file already exists? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351249/vba-check-if-file-exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA save the file on desktop, if name already taken add a numer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61751680/vba-save-the-file-on-desktop-if-name-already-taken-add-a-numer-to-it)